# Accidentally deleted a webpart, how can I get it back

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have deleted "New comment" webpart on the Blog Post detailed Page on the my SharePoint blog site, I am unable to find it in the webpart list.

How can I get undo / add the webpart back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have clicked the **`X`** button in the top-right corner of the web part, it is simply closed. You can get it back as follows:

1. Click on **Actions**, **Edit Page**
2. Click **Add a web part**
3. Click **Advanced Web Part Gallery** in the top bottom-right corner of the dialog
4. Click on **Closed Web Parts** in the tool pane on the right
5. Drag the closed web part from the tool pane back onto the page

If you have actually used the drop-down menu on the web part and clicked **Delete**, it really is deleted. If you have check-in/out available to the page you can go back to a previous version to restore it. Otherwise you will need to restore from backup if you have one.

Comment: Well praise the lord, I'd been afraid of that little x button since the beginning.

Comment: Let the random, uncontrolled clicking begin.

Answer (score 3):

A very usefull way to see all web parts on the page, including closed ones, is the Web Part Maintenance Page, which is accessed by simply adding '?Contents=1' to the page address

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem (it was my mistake :(), but I am able to get my “New Comment” webpart back on the page by using SharePoint Designer.

Steps to get “New Comment” webpart back on the page

1. Create New blog site just to get “New Comment” list form Webpart
2. Open Newly created blog site in SharePoint designer and  address]/ Lists/Posts/Post.aspx page and
3. Copy the full XSLT code of “New Comment” list form Webpart
4. Go back to your production blog site and place the copied XSLT just after “comments” list view Webpart on the page
5. Provide “your comments list GUID” under List Name property of the copied XSLT
6. Save and close.
7. That’ it. Your “New comment” Webpart is back on the page

Regards,
Moorthy Annadurai

Answer (score 1):

"If you have actually used the drop-down menu on the web part and clicked Delete, it really is deleted."

Here is a solution that does not require SP Designer and fixes the problem in a couple minutes.

In fact, it is only the Default View associated to the webpart that is deleted. Click on **View All Site Content**. Then on the defective library link. It will open the listedit.aspx page. Go down to the **Views** section. Select another view or create a new view and make it the one by default. That's it. You are back in business. Of course, you need to correct the library link in the Quick Launch section.

Regards, 
Pierre Audette

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a "Summary Link Web Part" that was added to a Document Library and the user accidentally "x'd" out off it.  I found the "closed" web part by doing the following:

1. Click on "Site Actions | Edit Page"
2. Click on "Add a Web Part"
3. In the "Categories" list box on the left the last folder is "Closed Web      Parts".  Select the Web Part and re-add it.